# Is negation literals Counts as a separate formula in Counting Sub-Formula of First-Order Formulas

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I count sub-formulas of this formula in a way which described [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3775416/counting-sub-formula-of-this-first-order-formula) but my answer for this particular formula is 13 but the correct answer is 11 , the only reason i guess is negation doesn't count but i read in this book that i should count negation as a separate formula. now i confused.

```
Applied Logic for Computer Scientists: Computational Deduction and Formal Proofs
```

$\newcommand{\fml}[1]{\underbrace{#1}_\text{formula}}$
$\newcommand{\Fml}[1]{\underbrace{#1}_\text{formula!}}$

$\fml{(\fml{(\fml{p}→ \fml{ \lnot \fml{q}})} \lor\fml{ \fml{((\fml{\fml{p} \land \fml{r}})→\fml{s})})→\fml{\lnot \fml{r}}}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negation does introduce a new formula, that you did alright.

If one counts distinct subformulas rather than *occurrences* of subformulas, then subformulas occurring multiple times only count once -- they are the same formula, just existing in multiple places. Subformulas in your book are probably defined as a set where the subformulas of a complex formula are the set union of the subformulas' subformulas; when you do $\{p\} \cup \{p\}$, the result will be $\{p, p\} = \{p\}$ with cardinality 1, not 2.
In your example, the formulas $p$ and $r$ each occur twice; their second occurrences don't count as additional subformulas, which gets you 2 down from 13 to 11. The syntax tree is precisely correct, but you count the number of *distinct* nodes.